# Dehydrator potato chips

Tags: potatoes, chips

I am trying to make potato chips using my dehydrator, but the keep coming out hard and plastic like. They are to hard to eat. I cut them at 1/16 of and inch and blanched them.

I used a low setting too.

Comment: Did you actually cook them at any point (beyond blanching)?

Comment: Indeed, they should be cooked in oil. Othervise the result would be very bland. 

Answer (score 7):

I'm not clear on what you are trying to achieve with the dehydrator.  I see three options for you.  Option 1: no dehydrator, just deep fry in oil.  This is probably the most traditional.  Option 2: use the dehydrator briefly (a matter of 10 - 30 minutes) to dry the potato slices. This would create less splattering when frying. Option 3: Cook the potato slices (this will gelatanize the starch), dehydrate until "plastic like", then fry.  This should allow the potatoes to puff when fried. In all scenarios, the potato must be cooked at some point to crisp them, which will not happen in the dehydrator.

Answer (score 3):

Potatoes need to be cooked before they are edible (or at least palatable).  Dehydrators only remove water from food, it does not cook the food.
So if you want to crisp potato chips, without frying it in oil, you might try steaming potato slices (slice them thicker than normal so that they will hold shape after steaming.  About 10 minutes of strong steaming should do the job.  Then dry the chips a bit before seasoning with salt and pepper. The dehydrator should produce better results for you.

I have not tried this method myself (I prefer deep fried chips), but this is how I would do it. If you try it, do let us know how it worked.